# Getting the Row and Column of a Triangular Matrix, Given the Index

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am working with a MxM triangular matrix which has the following form:

```
M = [m00 m10 m20 m30 m40]
    [m11 m21 m31 m41    ] 
    [m22 m32 m42        ]
    [m33 m43            ]
    [m44                ]
```

If it's easier to picture this in terms of indexes, it would look like this:

```
M = [0 1 3 6 10]  
    [2 4 7 11  ]
    [5 8 12    ]
    [9 13      ]
    [14        ]
```

I know this way of indexing might look odd but it would be much easier if I could keep the indexing system as it is in order for this module to work well with others.

I am struggling with an algorithm that takes an index and size of the matrix that can return the row and column that the given index falls under.  Ideally I would have 2 functions such as these:

```
int getRow (int index, int size);
int getCol (int index, int size);
```

So    `getRow (7, 5)` would return `3`

And    `getCol (7, 5)` would return `1`

I have come across this thread already but I cannot seem to modify the solution given there to work for the way I am indexing.

[algorithm for index numbers of triangular matrix coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242711/algorithm-for-index-numbers-of-triangular-matrix-coefficients)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I will make an edit. Even with that though, I still cant make seem to rework the algorithm given in the other topic to suit the way I am indexing.

Comment: why getRow (7, 5) would return 3?

Comment: Because the way I am indexing, the rows are the diagonals (not the horizontals) so row 3 is `m30, m31, m32, m33`

Comment: So your columns are normal and your rows diagonal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**New Answer**

You can find the `row` and `column` using the following formulas:

```
int row = floor(-0.5 + sqrt(0.25 + 2 * index));
int triangularNumber = row * (row + 1) / 2;
int column = index - triangularNumber;
```

This works because the first item in each row is a [triangular number](http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Triangular_number) (0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ...). So the biggest triangular number that is lower than `index` gives us the `row`. Then `column` is simply the difference between `index` and that triangular number.

Also, note that you don't need the parameter `M`.

---

**Old Answer**

This code will give you both the `row` and `column` of `index`.

```
int triangularNumber = 0;
int row = 0;
while (triangularNumber + row < index) {
    row ++;
    triangularNumber += row;
}
int column = index - triangularNumber;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems I was trying to figure it out algebraically which was causing me problems but this iterative solution works just as nicely.

Comment: @Redek, are you sure you want change matrix indexing and find row amd column in O(n)?

Comment: @Saeed Amiri, I would be open to a more efficient solution without a doubt but this solution does work well and for the system which I will be implementing this, the max size of this matrix will only be a few thousand which in my opinion is pretty negligible. That being said, I would certainly welcome other solutions for my own benefit and even for others who are running into a similar problem but cannot afford the O(n) limitation.

Comment: @sch it is O(n) because matrix is n*n, Also I agree with you because you answered, I can't understand why OP changed alignments to get this runtime!

Comment: @Saeed Amiri, I dont think I follow? How have I changed alignments? I am very happy with sch's solution, both for the explanation given and at how quickly he replied. As ideal as it would be to have the perfect O(1) solution, I do have other parts of the system that depend on this, which in turn does have a deadline so I am happy that I was able to come across a solution.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri - Finally, it was simple to find the formulas for `row` and `column`. There is only a second degree equation to solve.

Comment: @Redek, when I saw your question, I thought you plan to reduce memory size with efficient access time, but when I saw you are happy just by founding related functions, I thought it is a homework and there isn't any special reason to have such a functions.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri - Ohh no, the initial reason was not for efficiency, I was simply stumped on the problem. And no it's not for homework.